# Is there a Cake 3 replacement for sql_dump

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In CakePhp < 3 it was possible to get a list of the executed queries in a debug view using

```
echo $this->element('sql_dump');
```

In Cake 3 the according element file is no longer in the core. Is there a Cake 3 equivalent? I could not find anything about this in the migration guide.

Comment: If you're not using debug kit: you should be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure there are debugging features builtin.

You can use `debug()` as explained on Debugging [Queries and ResultSets](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#debugging-queries-and-resultsets).

But you should better add [DebugKit](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/debug-kit.html) and not only have the SQL in a tab for whenever you need it but also a wealth of debugging information.

Comment: I wanted to avoid to use DebugKit. But probably there is no real alternative for it.

Comment: There's no alternative to DebugKit simply because there exists no other tool that can provide so much information in one place. If you need a subset of information you can always do it manually however it fits you. If `debug()` is not enough, [query logging](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#query-logging) might be worth checking out.

Comment: In my cakephp 3 application, debugkit panel not showing but after uploading hosted server the panel showing. I can't find any solution for this.

Comment: How about asking stack overflow then @karim_fci? Comments are not the place to get answers.